# Regex JS: Searching between two same words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long text which contains some tags to highlight the text between. I need to match the text between these tags. 
Here is the list of tags: CA | OU | TC.

So I did this:

```
\[[CA|OU|TC]+\][\s\S]*?\[-[CA|OU|TC]+\]
```

It matches correctly these strings

```
[CA] bla bla [-CA]
[OU] bla[-OU]
[TC] blabla [-TC]
```

The problem is that I need to only match if the tags are the same. It should not match the following.

```
[CA] bla bla [-OU]
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\[(CA|OU|TC)][\s\S]*?\[-\1]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpFsCE/2).

The `(CA|OU|TC)` forms a capturing group and `\1` matches the same value.

```js
var s = '[CA] bla bla [-CA] [OU] bla[-OU] [TC] blabla [-TC]] [CA] bla bla [-OU]';
var rx = /\[(CA|OU|TC)][\s\S]*?\[-\1]/g;
console.log( s.match(rx) );
```